# Do compacta in $\mathbb R^n$ have finite Hausdorff measure?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

For $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ let $\mathcal H^s(A)$ be the $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure with respect to the Euclidean metric. The Hausdorff dimension of $A$ is given by $$\dim_H(A) = \inf\{s>0\mid\mathcal H^s(A)=0\}.$$ One of the go-to curiosities in measure theory courses is the fact the middle-third Cantor $C$ set has Hausdorff dimension $\log2/\log3$. This value is easily determined using a self-similarity argument *assuming* that $0<\mathcal H^s(C)<\infty$ for some $s$. However, verifying this assumption for $s=\log2/\log3$ is not quite as easy. Thinking about this and other self-similar objects got me wondering about a more general question:

> For non-empty, compact $K\subset\mathbb R^n$ of Hausdorff dimension $d$, is it automatic that $0<\mathcal H^d(K)<\infty$? In other words, do non-empty compacta in $\mathbb R^n$ have finite, non-zero Hausdorff measure in their Hausdorff dimension?

At first, I thought that the answer must be yes for the extreme cases $d=0$ and $d=n$ where the relevant Hausdorff measures are the counting measure and the Lebesgue measure (up to scaling). However, at some point I realized that I had implicitly assumed that Hausdorff dimension 0 or n would imply discreteness or non-empty interior (which may or may not be true, probably not).

I'm now at the point where I've realized that I have already spent much more time thinking about this than I should have. Hence, I resort to the infinite wisdom of the internet. I believe that the answer to the above question is no in the stated generality, but I'm basically at a loss. Maybe someone on here has something up their sleeve.

Comment: There are compact sets such that, for each positive real number $s,$ their $s$-measure is either $0$ or $\infty.$ Indeed, this is not especially difficult to achieve (see the middle of p. 485 of [this book review](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2000-37-04/S0273-0979-00-00878-8/S0273-0979-00-00878-8.pdf)). However, even more exotic situations can occur --- see [Existence of dimension function (i.e., exact gauge function)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915197)  and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dimensionless%22+Hausdorff+measure).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! The given references answer my question. I will accept the duplicate.

Comment: Wow, that 2-answer duplicate is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for (didn't look very long, however) when I wound up citing p. 485 of that book review!